# Append string to elements having same class name

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure what I need to change up, but I have two elements in separate div's with the same class name and I'm not sure how I can populate both of them.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <a class="this-thing">Text</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="this-thing">Text</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
const text = document.querySelectorAll(".this-thing");
text.innerHTML +='Add'
```

Not sure why it would work when I have one instance, but then if I add another element with the class `this-thing` it doesn't work at all.

Comment: "The Document method [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors." See the part **Accessing the matches**

Comment: Both `querySelectorAll()` and `innerHTML` ***waste performance of your app***, even for such a tiny use case, you may [boost your performance about 50%](https://jsbench.me/26k70z5okk/1) with slight change (look through [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384003/11299053) for details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList of elements. So you'll need to loop through them and add the text to each one.

```js
const text = document.querySelectorAll(".this-thing");
text.forEach(element => element.innerHTML += ' Add');
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="this-thing">Text</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="this-thing">Text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

[`Element.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) is usually [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384003/11299053) than `.querySelectorAll()` (and reads more naturally), so I would recommend to use the former.

Also, [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) would be better ([both faster and safer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML)) option to modify inner text of the node, so your line may be as simple, as:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('this-thing')].forEach(node => node.textContent += ' Add')
```

Following is the quick demo:

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('this-thing')].forEach(node => node.textContent += ' Add')
```

```html
<div><div class="this-thing">Some text</div></div><div><div class="this-thing">Some other text</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".this-thing").forEach(element => {
  element.innerHTML +='Add'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop into the results of `querySelectorAll()` :

```js
var texts = document.querySelectorAll(".this-thing");
for (let text in texts) {
    text.innerHTML += 'Add';
}
```

This is because the return value of `querySelectorAll()` isn't a single object, but a `NodeList` of objects as mentioned in [the documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) in the **Return value** section.

> The `Document` method `querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) `NodeList` representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.
>
> #### Return Value
>
> A non-live `NodeList` containing one `Element` object for each element that matches at least one of the specified selectors or an empty `NodeList` in case of no matches.